# Receipting for multiple event registrations via webform

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, receipts

We have a webform that allows you to register multiple people for multiple events. Once they have paid we would like them to receive an email receipt that they can print out and bring along to the event. How would we go about doing this?

Options we have explored are:

1. Webform emails: Yes you can format these to provide all the bits of information from the webform and format it however you like BUT it gets triggered to send as soon as you have submitted the form ie got pushed through to the payment page hence the email gets sent even if you do not then complete the payment.
2. If you have receipting on on the event then an event registration confirmation email gets sent. This only gets sent once the payment is completed but the email does not contain the correct information about all the events and participants.

Issues with the email are:

If you register contact 1 for event A and B and contact 2 for event A and C
then under the Event Information and Location heading it refers to event C and under event price there is an item for participant 1 and participant 2 referencing event A.

If you register contact 1 for event A and B and contact 2 for event C and D then under the Event Information and Location heading it refers to event D  and under event price there is just one item for one participant to event A.

Neither of these emails made reference to who participant 1 and 2 were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needed a fix in core. Have raised a JIRA for it at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20657. Hopefully it should be merged in 4.7.21 version.

Fix submitted at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10439

Comment: I nevertheless seem to have similar issues in 4.7.27 - if I register just one contact for two events, on the receipt, the event info and line items are mixed up - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/22777/68 - any idea ?

Comment: Ah yes this was a seperate issue, have commented on your question, we have resolved this for ourselves and will work on bundling it together to release back to the community