# webform event registration - no receipts from contribution page?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, webform-civicrm, receipts, 4.7.27

I have a webform that registers one participant for multiple events. payment is handled through one specific contribution page, that is set to send receipts.

But it sends nothing. Other webforms (like member fees) do send receipts.

- could it be a problem that there are multiple items on the webform ?
- am i supposed to enable 'online registration' for one, or all, of the events, and send receipts from there instead ?

I would prefer a single receipt for the whole transaction, but sending 10 receipts is better than sending none ...

Comment: what version of civicrm?

Comment: @Zachary 4.7.27, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to enable receipts on all the events as the receipt being sent is an event registration receipt rather than the contribution page receipt if the webform involves event registration.

When registering for multiple events via a webform only one email gets triggered even if you are signing up to multiple events. If I recall correctly it just used the email from the first event. We had to make a lot of changes to the event template to get the correct information in the email and created a custom extension in order to provide more tokens for the event template. We will attempt to get these bundled up so we can release this back to the community

We also made a change via a custom extension to allow you to turn on and provide the details for the email without having to turn on online registrations for the event.
[image]

Comment: love to see even a first draft of your 'bundle' to check what is involved !

Comment: We have released it as an extension here https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.webformparticipants. Note we  haven't done any testing of the extension yet. Let us know what you think and if it helps

Comment: Using this extension - to generally good effect, but can't work out how to include some values from custom participant fields that are on the webform (and in a profile that is referenced on the event page).

Answer (score 2):

To issue civicrm native event participant receipts when using webform civicrm module you must enable receipting for both the Contribution page as well as the Event page (in your CiviCRM) - for all Events; And yes that will be a number of receipts.

If multiple receipts is a problem - you can  use webform native receipting + use CiviRules and custom (last) contribution tokens - to send a transaction rceipt;

If you’d like to try that - Register for CiviCamp Calgary - it's a form where orgs can sign up 3 participants for up to 4 events/each in on one page;

**Added:** webform civicrm works with CiviCRM via it's API: from adding donations to memberships and sign up for multiple events all in one form and using sendConfirmation api to send out the native CiviCRM event receipts; CiviCRM gets a little confused we're able to get all that in one payment [natively that's not possible] - reason why I tend to dispatch my own receipts with Rules/Message templates and some custom tokens;

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm, you are saying : webform civicrm event registration *never* uses the contribution page to send a receipt, it always tries to use the event receipts ? and you have to enable both to get it working. is that right ?

Comment: OK - tried that. Signed up for 3 events and it sent 1 receipt. The event details mentioned in the receipt are from one event; the single line-item under event fees is taken from another event. It's just wrong info .. is that a known bug in 4.7.27 ?