# Event confirmation receipts don't send when registering via Civi webform

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, email

I've replicated this on:

- CiviCRM 5.57.4, Drupal 7.94, webform 7.x-4.25, Civi webform 7.x-5.8
- CiviCRM 5.50.1, Drupal 9.4.5, webform 6.1.3, Civi webform 6.2.1

When registering for an event (paid or not - I've tried both) via a webform, the receipt does not send.  In the case of the paid event, both contribution and event receipting was turned on (per this [webform event registration - no receipts from contribution page?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22776/webform-event-registration-no-receipts-from-contribution-page/22789#22789)); the contribution receipt went out but the event receipt did not.  In the case of the non-paid event, no receipt went out.

Receipting works correctly when registering from the Civi-generated form, so either I'm missing something in the webform configuration or there's another issue.  Any help appreciated!